# Different Font styles in Editplus

Tags: text-editors, text-editing

I would like to have keywords to be appear Bold and variable names,Comments and Strings should be in normal style. is that possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own custom Syntax Highlighting rules in EditPlus using .stx files. There is information about how to do this in the EditPlus help file - search for syntax highlighting.

> In order to add your own syntax type, you must create a syntax file and add it on Settings & Syntax page of the Preferences dialog box.
>
> Syntax file is a plain text file which has ".STX" extension and should be written in predefined format. The format is very simple. The fastest way is to look into the sample .STX file such as JS.STX for JavaScript files (*.JS).

But you'd need to find a way of denoting what is a variable and what is a keyword... this maybe possible if you code with consistency, e.g. use [CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) for variable names and use  for comments.

You might find another EditPlus user has already created a syntax file that meets your requirements. Check out the [repository of EditPlus syntax files](http://www.editplus.com/files.html).